# How to make Excel recognise Dukascopy date time format

Tags: excel, date, formula

I'm working with a date and time format from the Dukascopy csv download format. It looks like this:

01.03.2018 07:00:00.000 GMT-0000.

Is there a formula to convert this to a format that could be sorted chronologically? I don't need the -0000, just the date and time. Thank you.

Comment: Is your sample date ***January 3*** or ***March 1***

Answer (score 2):

Please try:

```
=DATE(MID(A1,7,4),MID(A1,4,2),MID(A1,1,2))+TIMEVALUE(MID(A1,12,12))
```

with formatting to suit.

Switch around the second and third parameters of `DATE` (the `4` and the `1`) to suit the date convention of your source, if required.

Comment: To answer 'Gary's Student' the format was March 1. But the solution from pnuts has resolved this but my lack of clarity has been noted so I very appreciated the question.

Comment: Yes, thank you pnuts, this was my first night on this forum and I didn't see the request for clarification. In fact I thanked you before noticing Gary Student's query, then thanked him before noticing your follow up. In fact I really didn't expect an answer tonight! I'll catch on quickly!

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
=--SUBSTITUTE(LEFT(A1,20),".","/")
```

Then format as desired.

This only works if the input and the local settings agree as to order of MM/DD or DD/MM.

[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ohWU4.png]

Comment: @pnuts added note.

Comment: I'm betting this is originating from Germany, currenlly is `dd.MM.yyyy`, and that the Windows regional date format is `yyyy-MM-dd` and that therefore this won't work.  (My region, Canada, is also yyyy-mm-dd, and you're correct, the formula didn't like it.) I wonder if my prediction is correct...